# Issue with string replacing and regex

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a function to convert urls to working links. This must convert every form: full url like `http://link.com`, without the protocol like `www.link.com`, even with just the extension like `link.com`.

So far my function is working but there is a weird bug when there is several times the same link in a string.

```
import re
import cgi

def process_links(string):
    """Convert urls to links in a string"""
    # http + https
    links = re.findall("(https?://[^\s]+)", string)
    # www
    links2 = re.findall("(w{3}\.[^\s]+)", string)
    # only extension
    links3 = re.findall("([^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})", string)
    links = links + links2 + links3
    # remove duplicates
    links = list(set(links))
    string = cgi.escape(string)
    for link in links:
        # make sure the href attr starts with http|https
        if re.match('https?://', link) is None:
            http_link = 'http://'+link
        else:
            http_link = link
        htmlLink = '<a href="'+http_link+'">'+link+'</a>'
        string = re.sub(link, htmlLink, string)
    return string
```

Working and failing examples:

```
# working
string = 'firstlink.com and www.secondlink.com'
# output:
# '<a href="http://firstlink.com">firstlink.com</a> and <a href="http://www.secondlink.com">www.secondlink.com</a>    

# failing: when there are several times the same link
string = 'firstlink.com and http://firstlink.com
# output:
# <a href="<a href="http://firstlink.com">http://firstlink.com</a>">firstlink.com</a> and http://<a href="<a href="http://firstlink.com">http://firstlink.com</a>">firstlink.com</a>
```

I've never tried to use regex this "complicated" in python and can't figure out why there is this weird behavior. I think this comes from the `re.sub()` part where it may replace something that has already been replaced?

PS: my function is probably not the best and can certainly be improved, if you have any suggestions I'm listening

Comment: The first time through the loop, re.sub will replace *all* occurrences of firstlink.com with <a href="http://firstlink.com">firstlink.com</a>, and the second time through the loop, re.sub will replace *all* occurrences of http://firstlink.com with <a href="http://firstlink.com">http://firstlink.com</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to process the links *as you find them*, and find all forms with *one* regular expression. Using `re.sub()` and a replacement function would be the easiest:

```
def linkify(match):
    link = match.group(1)
    http_link = link if re.match('https?://', link) else 'http://' + link
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(http_link, link)

links = re.compile(r'(https?://[^\s]+|w{3}\.[^\s]+|[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})')
string = links.sub(linkify, string)
```

By combining the 3 forms into one pattern you prevent matching the same link multiple times, and by using the replacement function you also avoid replacing multiple occurences where a shorter form of the same link is used (a linked `http://firstlink.com` still contains the `firstlink.com` part for future replacement calls).

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'firstlink.com and www.secondlink.com'
>>> links.sub(linkify, string)
'<a href="http://firstlink.com">firstlink.com</a> and <a href="http://www.secondlink.com">www.secondlink.com</a>'
>>> string = 'firstlink.com and http://firstlink.com'
>>> links.sub(linkify, string)
'<a href="http://firstlink.com">firstlink.com</a> and <a href="http://firstlink.com">http://firstlink.com</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use the compile method but couldn't get it to work